# How to perform upsampling using the convolution_transpose function ?

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim, deconvolution

I want to use the convolution_transpose function of tf.slim and it seems that, no matter how I choose my kernel size and strides, I cannot get the output of the convolution_transpose layer to be larger than that of the initial convolutional layer. Am I missing something here?